# Sorting a dictionary by keys in the order in an Arraylist

Tags: c#, dictionary, arraylist

I was asked the following question in an interview. How can I sort a Dictionary by the key, in the order which is in an array list.

So for example I have a dictionary as follows

```
Dictionary<string, string> stringDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

stringDict.Add("1", "One");
stringDict.Add("7", "Seven");
stringDict.Add("6", "Six");
stringDict.Add("2", "Two");
stringDict.Add("3", "Three");
stringDict.Add("5", "Five");
stringDict.Add("4", "Four");
```

And an array list as follows

```
ArrayList stringArList = new ArrayList();

stringArList.Add("1");
stringArList.Add("2");
stringArList.Add("3");
stringArList.Add("5");
stringArList.Add("6");
stringArList.Add("7");
stringArList.Add("4");
```

How can I sort the dictionary in the order it is in the array list?

Comment: Hmm.  My answer would be "dictionaries don't have an order".  Then if they didn't hire me because of that, I would know that I wouldn't want to work for them anyways. :)

Comment: ...unless it is an ordered dictionary.

Comment: I agree with D Stanley - most likely this is a trick question. These interview questions are really outdated, in my opinion, and need to be replaced with just good old fashioned "can you solve this valid problem and how would you do it" coding time.  Questions like this one are created by somewhat-senior engineers to boost their own self-esteem. (I know that, because I've created many of them...then I realized that I don't need to use interviews to boost my self-esteem...I'm really good at what I do and my actions prove it. Proving that I'm more clever than someone I'm interviewing does not.)

Comment: "Questions like this one are created by somewhat-senior engineers to boost their own self-esteem" I couldn't agree more...

Comment: This exact question was asked earlier this morning.  Cant find it off hand however.  I thought that @DStanley actually answered it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can't sort a Dictionary per se, but you *can* extract the key-values pairs as a list and sort *those*:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs = 
    stringDict.OrderBy(kvp => stringArList.IndexOf(kvp.Key));
```

But there's not a way to "traverse" dictionary items in any particular order.

You could create a `SortedDictionary` and provide an `IComparer<string>`

```
var d = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(stringDict, 
                                        new PositionComparer(stringArList));
```

With the `Comparer` implementation as:

```
public class PositionComparer : IComparer<string>
{
   private ArrayList Keys {get; set;}

   public PositionComparer(ArrayList keys)
   {
       Keys = keys;
   }

   public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
   {
       return Keys.IndexOf(s1).CompareTo(Keys.IndexOf(s2));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will produce a list of the values sorted as required.

```
var sortedValues = stringDict.OrderBy(pair => stringArList.IndexOf(pair.Key))
                             .Select(pair => pair.Value)
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As said many times before in this question, a C# `Dictionary` can not be sorted. This is inherent to the implementation. As you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the dictionary is implemented using a Hashtable. This means that those items don't have any ordering. You can't say "give me the first element of this dictionary". There simply is no first, second or last element. The only thing you can say about an element in a dictionary is that it has a unique identifier which determines it's location in the dictionary (with a little help from the hash function).

When you have an element in an `array` for example, you can say "this element is the next element" or "this element is the previous element". Each element in an array has a previous and a next. This does not hold for dictionaries.

When you insert an item into the dictionary it will generate a hash (a fairly unique number) based on the key. For example, a very simple (and bad) hash of keys consisting of names would be to take the sum of each character presented as their ASCII value in the name, and then add those together. The result is a number, say 5, then we would insert the value in a store (an array for example) on position 5. If however, at position 5 is another value, which happens to have the same hash result you have a `collision`. How you solve these, and how you avoid these is what hashtables are all about. See the Wiki for more information on this.

When you request your value with your key `someName` it will hash that value and look it up at that position.

Hashtables are not as easy as I just explained, there is a lot too it. You can read more on the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

So the answer to "Sort this dictionary" is most definitely "No can do.". However, you can convert it to a sortable data structure like a list, or whatever and then sort it.

Answer (score 0):

I replied with the following answer.

```
  var list = from arElement in stringArList.ToArray().ToList()
                   join dict in stringDict on arElement equals dict.Key 
                   select dict ;
```

But the interviewer didn't seem to be impressed.

Comment: You didn't actually order the items based on their position in the arraylist.

Comment: Well I am not sure what you mean, but I am able to sort it (rather create a new dictionary) by the order in the Array list.  I ran it and it seems to work fine. Can you please elaborate on why you think this wouldn't work ?

Comment: Oh okay I think I understand what you mean here. You are right, there is no way I can sort the original dictionary. In fact I asked the person who was interviewing me as to how he would approach the problem, being the dumb ass he was he just muffled some thing which was not clear to me and neither did it make sense. It was quite obvious he did not know the right answer either.

Comment: Interview questions like that are usually designed not to get the "right answer" but to see _how you think_.  How do you approach the problem?  Either either or an attempt to boost the interviewer's ego by humiliating the interviewee :)

Answer (score 0):

`original_dic.OrderBy` returns `IOrderedEnumerable`, that you convert to a new dictionary.

```
var ordered_dic = original_dic.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=> x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using it like below:

```
stringDict = stringDict.OrderBy(x => stringArList.IndexOf(x.Key)).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```